# How to set width of a widget (programmatically)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I trying to set the width of a Button.And I tried like this:

```
buttonX.Width = 20;
```

and like this:

```
butomn.SetWidth = 20;
```

And both methods doesn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kevskree is almost correct.

You don't **always** use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, it depends on what type the parent view is. So if the parent of the `Button` is a `RelativeLayout`, you use its `LayoutParams`, if it is a `LinearLayout` you use its params etc. Some `LayoutParams` such as the one for `RelativeLayout` contain extra stuff such as rules for relative alignment and much more than the simple `LayoutParams`, which `LinearLayout` provides. There are some parent views which contain a very extensive set of `LayoutParams` so make sure you use the correct one, if you want to make use of those.

However for simple width and height and ignoring the rest of the parameters able to be set, you can just use the base which is the one from `ViewGroup`. So:

```
buttonX.LayoutParameters = 
    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(20, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```

Comment: this is the 16th question tonight you've answered for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the LayoutParameters for the button. So something like this

```
buttonX.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20, buttonX.Height);
```

You may have to adjust the type of LinearLayout.LayoutParams depending on the parent layout type your button is sitting in.